# I'm so confused with Null hypothesis and Alternative hypothesis in this solution

Tags: probability, statistics

So the question says "A company that claims the average time a customer waits on hold is less than $5$ minutes. A sample of $35$ customers have an average wait time of $4.78$ minutes . Assume the population standard deviation for the wait time is $1.6$ minutes. Test the company's claim"

So to me the null hypothesis is the status quo therefore $H_0\lt 5$ whereas the alternative hypothesis $H_1$ should be $H_1\ge5$

However the official answer to this solution is completely opposite it's stated $H_0\ge5$ , $H_1\lt5$

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't missing anything.

Your answer is **mathematically completely correct**.

Unfortunately, there are people out there, who **try to set up fixed rules when setting up the hypotheses** like "status quo is always $H_0$ and claim is always $H_1$" or the other way round. Fact is, **there is no general fixed rule of this type.**

In your case, you can carry out a hypothesis test **both** for

- $H_0: \mu \lt 5$ vs. $H_1: \mu \geq 5$ **and**
- $H_0: \mu \geq 5$ vs. $H_1: \mu \lt 5$

Important is, that the hypotheses are designed in a way, such that a meaningful test statistic can be calculated.

For example, when testing data for following a certain distribution using $\chi^2$-tests, $H_0$ **is exactly the claim**.

**Nevertheless, in many cases**, there is a status quo which is often set to be $H_0$. The claim is then $H_1$ (something has changed, the status quo is probably not valid anymore).

Then, you test whether there is enough statistical evidence which supports that $H_0$ is rather improbable. $H_0$ is considered to be improbable if the test value of the sample is improbable under the assumption that $H_0$ is true given a certain significance level $\alpha$.

Comment: It is usually the case that the type-2 error should be minimized while just having the type-1 bounded by some $\alpha$. Thus, in cases where there's an asymmetry between false negatives and false positives you want the wrongful "acceptance" of $H_0$ to be a false negative. In the OP's case there's no asymmetry, so I guess the choice doesn't matter.

Comment: @trancelocation - Lovely answer!  In other words, are you working for the company, or are you working for its rival?  :D

Answer (score 0):

In statistics, the alternative hypothesis is what we wish to show. In this case, the company wishes to show that the average time a customer waits on hold is less than $5$ minutes.

We have

$$\frac{4.78-5}{1.6/\sqrt{35}}\sim \mathsf N(0,1)$$

Since $$\Phi\left(\frac{4.78-5}{1.6/\sqrt{35}}\right)\approx\Phi(-0.813)\approx0.208$$

we fail to reject the null hypothesis at $\alpha=0.05$. We do not have significant evidence that the average time a customer waits on hold is less than $5$ minutes.

Comment: thank you for your answer I think I know why I messed up

Comment: For example, when testing data for following a certain distribution using $\chi^2$-tests, $H_0$ **is exactly what you wish to show**.